# Active Monitoring in Production - Java Spring Docker

Tags: java, docker

I have 15 container of spring boot microservices and they generate logs individually.
When I have a problem in production we go into the logs and investigate using grep for the date | ERROR | etc.

```
docker logs df93d841cb48 | grep "2021-06-01 01:52:37.351 ERROR"
```

Works very well but we want an active monitoring daily, like if an ERROR is found in the logs, generate a file with the errors at the end of the day, send an email or similar to that.

Can anyone give an advice on what to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), I've been using it and it's pretty solid. Also [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) it's nice (it collects, aggregates, processes, and exports information about running containers) also if you [enable](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md) experimental features for docker engine (not recommended for Prod) you can [configure](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/) the Docker daemon as Prometheus target

Last but not least, docker engine itself exposes some of the core metrics, for example you can take the **running** containers names using  `docker ps` and then just make a call to the following API

```sh
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/<CONTAINER>/stats
```

For metrics related to CPU, memory ,network you can use.

```sh
docker stats
```